# How to get all text from HTML code using awk or grep or sed?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Here is an example of html code I have in a file:

```
+ "name": "Product 1",
- <title>Cool</title>
+ Nice music
- Great music
- <a class="button" href="/url" data-name="buy">Buy <span class="product">Product 1</span></a>
+ <a class="button" href="/index" data-name="buy">Buy <span class="product">Product 1</span></a>
- Product (1st generation)
+ Product <br class="break" />(1st generation)
- Cool
+ Not cool
- <li> Nice > cool > good. ok.</li>
+ <li> Nice > cool > good. Tap.</li>
+<meta property="track" content="page_1" />
+<meta property="track" content="page_2" />
+ "name": "Product 2",
```

Expected output:

```
+ "name": "Product 1",
- Cool
+ Nice music
- Great music
- Buy Product 1
+ Buy Product 1
- Product (1st generation)
+ Product (1st generation)
- Cool
+ Not cool
- Nice > cool > good. ok.
+ Nice > cool > good. Tap.
+ "name": "Product 2",
```

Here is my code

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="<";FS=">"}NF>1{printf "%s", $NF ""}'
```

I get following result which is not expected:

```
Cool
+ Nice music
- Great music
- Buy Product 1
+ Buy Product 1
- Product (1st generation)
+ Product (1st generation)
- Cool
+ Not cool
-  good. ok.
+  good. Tap.
+
+
+ "name": "Product 2",
```

How to get expected result using grep or awk or sed? It should be able to get all text file from a html page.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/<[^<>]*>//g;/^[+-]\s*$/d' file
```

Remove all tags.

Remove empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
+ "name": "Product 1",
- <title>Cool</title>
+ Nice music
- Great music
- <a class="button" href="/url" data-name="buy">Buy <span class="product">Product 1</span></a>
+ <a class="button" href="/index" data-name="buy">Buy <span class="product">Product 1</span></a>
- Product (1st generation)
+ Product <br class="break" />(1st generation)
- Cool
+ Not cool
- <li> Nice > cool > good. ok.</li>
+ <li> Nice > cool > good. Tap.</li>
+<meta property="track" content="page_1" />
+<meta property="track" content="page_2" />
+ "name": "Product 2",
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="<[^>]*>";OFS=""}{$1=$1}/.../' file.txt
```

gives output

```
+ "name": "Product 1",
- Cool
+ Nice music
- Great music
- Buy Product 1
+ Buy Product 1
- Product (1st generation)
+ Product (1st generation)
- Cool
+ Not cool
-  Nice > cool > good. ok.
+  Nice > cool > good. Tap.
+ "name": "Product 2",
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is `<` followed by zero or more (`*`) not (`^`) `>` followed by `>` and output field separator (`OFS`) is empty string. For each line I do `$1=$1` to trigger string rebuilt. Then I select line which matches `...` expression, that is only lines having at least 3 characters. **Disclaimer**: HTML is not Chomsky Type 3 contraption and therefore can not be robustly parsed using regular expression, proposed code use certain heuristic which hopefully will work well enough with data you want to process.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*